# como cargar una tabla previamente filtrada?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, datatables

HOla estoy comenzando en este mundo quisiera saber si alguien me puede dar una mano con lo que quiero lograr hacer, la idea es cargar una tabla mediante json pero que esta muestre solo los registros que coinciden con alguna variable que pienso traer desde otra pagina ya sea por variable de sesion o post o get(como por ejemplo lo serian todos los registros que coincidan con numero de art para mi ejemplo). mi codigo de la carga es...

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-AddBookDialog", function () {
            var myUserName = $(this).data('art');
        $(".modal-body #UserName").val( myUserName );
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tabla_stk').DataTable({
            "columns": [
                {"data": "art"},
                {"data": "descripcion"},
                {"data": "marca"},
                {"data": "modelo"},
                {"data": "stock"},
                {     // fifth column (Borrar link)
                    "sName": "Agregar",
                    "bSearchable": false,
                    "bSortable": false,
                    "mData": "art",
                    "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                            //var id = full[2]; //row id in the first column
                            //return "<a href='javascript:alert(Borrar);'>Borrar</a>";
                            //return '<button type="button" data-id='+data+' class="open-AddBookDialog btn  btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-deluser">Borrar</button>';
                            return '<a href="#" data-art='+data+' class="open-AddBookDialog" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-addpre"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-fw"></i></a>';
                    }
                }
            ],
            "processing": true,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bFilter": true,
            "bpaginate": false,
            "serverSide": true,
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "iDisplayLength": "4", 
            "bInfo" : false,
            "pagingType": "numbers",
            "ajax": {
                url: 'tablastk.php',
                type: 'POST'
            }
        });
    });
```

el otro archivos tablastk.php que contiene mi conexion y demas.

```
if (!empty($_POST) ) {

    /*
     * Database Configuration and Connection using mysqli
     */

    define("HOST", "localhost");
    define("USER", "root");
    define("PASSWORD", "");
    define("DB", "bd");
    define("MyTable", "tblrep");

    $connection = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DB) OR DIE("Impossible to access to DB : " . mysqli_connect_error());

    /* END DB Config and connection */

    /*
     * @param (string) SQL Query
     * @return multidim array containing data array(array('column1'=>value2,'column2'=>value2...))
     *
     */
    function getData($sql){
        global $connection ;//we use connection already opened
        $query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) OR DIE ("Can't get Data from DB , check your SQL Query " );
        $data = array();
        foreach ($query as $row ) {
            $data[] = $row ;
        }
        return $data;
    }

    /* Useful $_POST Variables coming from the plugin */
    $draw = $_POST["draw"];//counter used by DataTables to ensure that the Ajax returns from server-side processing requests are drawn in sequence by DataTables
    $orderByColumnIndex  = $_POST['order'][0]['column'];// index of the sorting column (0 index based - i.e. 0 is the first record)
    $orderBy = $_POST['columns'][$orderByColumnIndex]['data'];//Get name of the sorting column from its index
    $orderType = $_POST['order'][0]['dir']; // ASC or DESC
    $start  = $_POST["start"];//Paging first record indicator.
    $length = $_POST['length'];//Number of records that the table can display in the current draw
    /* END of POST variables */

    $recordsTotal = count(getData("SELECT * FROM ".MyTable));

    /* SEARCH CASE : Filtered data */
    if(!empty($_POST['search']['value'])){

        /* WHERE Clause for searching */
        for($i=0 ; $i<count($_POST['columns']);$i++){
            $column = $_POST['columns'][$i]['data'];//we get the name of each column using its index from POST request
            $where[]="$column like '%".$_POST['search']['value']."%'";
        }
        $where = "WHERE ".implode(" OR " , $where);// id like '%searchValue%' or name like '%searchValue%' ....
        /* End WHERE */

        $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM %s %s", MyTable , $where);//Search query without limit clause (No pagination)

        $recordsFiltered = count(getData($sql));//Count of search result

        /* SQL Query for search with limit and orderBy clauses*/
        $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM %s %s ORDER BY %s %s limit %d , %d ", MyTable , $where ,$orderBy, $orderType ,$start,$length  );
        $data = getData($sql);
    }
    /* END SEARCH */
    else {
        $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM %s ORDER BY %s %s limit %d , %d ", MyTable ,$orderBy,$orderType ,$start , $length);
        $data = getData($sql);

        $recordsFiltered = $recordsTotal;
    }

    /* Response to client before JSON encoding */
    $response = array(
        "draw" => intval($draw),
        "recordsTotal" => $recordsTotal,
        "recordsFiltered" => $recordsFiltered,
        "data" => $data
    );

    echo json_encode($response);

} else {
    echo "NO POST Query from DataTable";
}
?>
```

Comment: En lugar de DataTable ¿no debería ser dataTable? por otro lado no está claro cuál es la pregunta. Por favor, sigue el [tour] y lee [ask].

Comment: si ruben es dataTable la cuestion es que quiero cargar mi tabla pero solo los registros que matcheen con un campo de la tabla coincidentes con una variable de session. $_SESSION['numcli'];desdeya muchas gracias y disculpas por si soy poco claro repito estoy empezando en esto y quiza no soy muy claro por ignorancia

Comment: No te preocupes, aquí no se juzga a las personas, sólo al contenido. Al usar JavaScript debes tener cuidado con el uso apropiado de mayúsculas y minúsculas en los operadores, funciones y variables pues un error de estos hace que el código no funcione como se espera. Si no lo has hecho aún, revisa [mcve]. Ahí se indican varias recomendaciones que te servirán para solucionar el problema o en su defecto hacer una pregunta más clara.

Answer (score 0):

Si vas a enviar informacion adicional antes de cargar la tabla solo hay que añadir la informacion al `ajax`

```
.../*Código anterior*/
"ajax": {
    url: 'tablastk.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: function ( d ) {
        //d contiene los parámetros por default que envía datatables
        d.myKey = "myValue";
        // d.custom = $('#myInput').val();
        // etc
    }
}
.../*Código posterior*/
```

En tu PHP tendrías algo como esto para capturar el valor de esa nueva variable

```
$myKey = $_POST["myKey"];//Capturando la variable personalizada enviada
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta Juan..perdon mi ignorancia estoy nuevito en esto... no comprendo donde tengo que poner mi variable.. yo tengo una variable definida como variable de sesion que traigo desde otrapagina $_session['id'] la idea es que mi tabla muestre solo los registros que macheen con esa variable

Comment: intente poner esto...            "ajax": {
                 url: 'tablarep.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: function ( d ) {
                            //d contiene los parámetros por default que envía datatables
                        d.myKey = "myValue";
                        // d.custom = $('#myInput').val();
                        // etc
                                     }
                    }
        }); y capturar la variable al comienzo de mi codigo de la siguiente manera....$myKey = $_SESSION['numcli'];

Comment: @Bruno si el dato lo obtienes de otra pagina y lo tienes el una variable de sesión no es necesario agregar el `data` al `ajax` solo con que lo captures desde el PHP en tu clausula `where` y lo utilices ahí, lo que yo coloque es para cuando tienes el valor en la vista o en Javascript